# Why isn't the component rendering the correct information? ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm rendering an array of values and I have a two buttons, one to `Add` and another to `Remove`. Everything works the way it should but when I click `Remove`, the element in the correct index gets removed from the array but when it renders again, it removes the last entry, and not the entry at that specific index.

**For example:** *(left side is webpage, right side is console)*

[image]

Currently the array is `["hello", "world", "everyone"]` and let's say I want to remove `"world"` and I click the `Remove` button next to it, the array updates correctly (I did a console.log) and it becomes `["hello", "everyone"]`, it re-renders but it shows it as if the array was `["hello", "world"]` and renders it incorrectly:

[image]

I'm not sure what I did incorrectly with my code as the array gets updated correctly and everything else seems to be okay.

```
    childChange: function(name, valid, value) {

        this.state.values = this.props.values;
        var pattern = /[0-9]+/;                                             // Using regex to find last digits from 0-9
        var match = name.match(pattern);                                    // Update state
        var i = parseInt(match);                                            // Parse char into int
        // console.log(match);

        this.state.values[i] = value;

        this.setState(this.state);

        this.props.callback(                                                // Call parent callback
            this.props.name,
            this.props.node.valid(this.state.values),
            this.state.values
        );
    },

    addEmptyItem: function() {

        this.state.values = this.props.values;
        this.state.values.push("");
        this.setState(this.state);

    },

    removeItem: function(ev) {

        console.log(ev.currentTarget.dataset.index);
        var i = parseInt(ev.currentTarget.dataset.index);
        this.state.values = this.props.values;
        this.state.values.splice(i,1);
        console.log(this.state.values);
        this.setState(this.state.values);

    },

        render: function() {
            var that = this;

            console.log("===RENDER===");

            return (
                <div id = "form">
                {this.props.values.map(function(v, i) {
                    return (

                        <div>
                            {(that.props.node.get().constructor.name === "Parent") ?
                            <ParentComponent
                                name={that.props.name + i}
                                key={i}
                                timer={that.props.timer}
                                callback={that.childChange}
                                values={v}
                                newParent={that.props.node.get()}
                            />
                            :
                            <div>
                                <NodeComponent
                                    name={that.props.name + i}
                                    key={i}
                                    timer={that.props.timer}
                                    callback={that.childChange}
                                    value={v}
                                    newNode={that.props.node.get()}
                                />

                            </div>

                            }
                            <button data-index={i} onClick={that.removeItem}>Remove
                            </button>
                        </div>

                    )
                })}
                <button onClick={() => that.addEmptyItem()}>Add
                </button>

                </div>
           )

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your function to look like this:

```
removeItem: function(ev) {

        console.log(ev.currentTarget.dataset.index);
        var i = parseInt(ev.currentTarget.dataset.index);
        let values = [...this.props.values];
        values.splice(i,1);
        console.log(this.state.values);
        this.setState(values);

    }
```

Why? when you use react state, you **never** changing it directly. you might look about it in [this article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/handling-state-in-react-four-immutable-approaches-to-consider-d1f5c00249d5).
what you did here, is you changed the state and then you called 'setState', that doesn't work. you should create new variable, manipulate over the new variable, and then call the setState with the new variable

Comment: Even after creating the new variable and manipulating it and calling setState, I wasn't able to get it to render correctly. It updated the new `values` array in removeItem but doesn't render correctly

Comment: I can see that you render the props.values in you render function instead of the state.values, witch you just updated, might it be your problem?

Comment: I don't believe so? I've been rendering it using `props.values` and it hasn't had any problems, even with the `addEmptyItem`. I'm not sure what else could be the issue.

Comment: I would just suggest you to reorganize your code, it's too messy that you changing the state and the props at the same time. 
Try to rewrite your component in one of those ways: 1. render the state.values instead of the prop.values. 2. keep rendering the state.props, but don't keep state but the delete would happen in the parent component.